# Is possible simplify generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

Colleagues, 
In our project we are using AutoMapper to map models.

We have a model:

```
public class Location
{
   public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public Collection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

also we have a view model:

```
public class PersonView
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Location { get; set;}
}
```

To mapping a model to a view model we may define something like the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>(d=>d.Name, opt=>opt.FromMap(s=>s.Name);
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>(d=>d.Address, opt=>opt.FromMap(s=>s.Locations.First().Address);
```

BUT: If Locations will not contains elements or is null then we will get an exception.

From other side, we may define a function to get a value:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>(d=>d.Address, opt=>opt.FromMap(s=>
{
    var item = s.Locations.FirstOrDefault();
    if(item == null)
    {
       return string.Empty;
    }

    return item.Address;
});
```

This expressions hard to read. And I try create a IValueResolver for simplify mapping.

```
public class CollectionItemResolver<TSource, TSourceItem, TResult>
    where TSource : class
    where TSourceItem : class
{
    private readonly Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSourceItem>> _sourceSelector;
    private readonly Func<TSourceItem, TResult> _selector;
    private readonly TResult _defaultValue;

    public CollectionItemResolver(Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSourceItem>> source, Func<TSourceItem, TResult> selector)
        : this(source, selector, default(TResult))
    {
    }

    public CollectionItemResolver(Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSourceItem>> source, Func<TSourceItem, TResult> selector, TResult defaultValue)
    {
        _sourceSelector = source;
        _selector = selector;
        _defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public TResult Resolve(TSource source)
    {
        var items = _sourceSelector(source);

        if (items == null)
        {
            return _defaultValue;
        }

        var item = items.FirstOrDefault();
        if (item == null)
        {
            return _defaultValue;
        }

        var value = _selector(item);
        return value;
    }
}
```

And then use something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>(d=>d.Address, opt=>opt.ResolveUsing(
    new CollectionItemResolver<Person, Location, string>(p=>p.Locations, i=>i.Address)));
```

Is possible simplify generic resolver?
For instance do not define the type of nested item?

```
new CollectionItemResolver<Person, string>(p=>p.Locations, i=>i.Address)));
```

Thanks,

Comment: I'd go back to the expression. That was much easier to read for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonView>(d=>d.Address, opt=>opt.FromMap(s=>s.Locations.Select(loc=>loc.Address).FirstOrDefault());
```

Buy the way, `Automapper` knows how to convert `Null` to `string.Empty`

PS, hope you have collection `Locations` always not null. 
But if not, then I suggest use this [extension](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/08/linq-query-operators-and-null-lists/):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> NullToEmpty<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<TSource>();

    return source;
}
```

Then result will be something like this: 
    opt=>opt.FromMap(s=>s.Locations.NullToEmpty().Select(loc=>loc.Address).FirstOrDefault());